# How to override/stop problem decorator provided by platform SDK

Tags: eclipse-plugin, overlay, decorator

I have referred to http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html and understand that having custom decorators that conflict with SDK decorators is a bad practice.

Though, I have an exception. In project I work we store information about various model elements under one physical resource file. The model elements get represented as separate nodes in project explorer. When we compile these nodes I want to mark error on the resource with line number indicating the exact element with error and thus project reflecting that it has errors. But at same time in Project explorer I do not want all nodes stored in that resource to have problem markers.Only node that had error should have the problem marker.

I have tried setting up custom decorator at BOTTOM_LEFT position(using both lightweight and non), but I always get the SDK problem overlay show.

Are there any other ways to make this work?

Here is an example.

We have a file called nodes.xml where we save our emf model. The nodel.xml looks like

```
<xml>
<rootnode name="root">
   <childnode name="child1"/>
   <childnode name="child2"/>
   <rootnode name="subroot">
     <childnode name="subchild1"/>
     <childnode name="subchild2"/>
   </rootnode>
</rootnode>
</xml>
```

All of the above nodes get represented in project explorer as different nodes of tree structure under project. As part of validation we validate each node root, child1, child2 etc separately. If validation fails for child1 I want to add a problem marker such that error gets marked in Problem View on file nodes.xml at line 3, but in project explorer want the error bottom_left overlay show up only on child1, root and project node and not on other nodes such as child2, subroot etc.

Hope this explains what I am trying to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the approach you are taking is the right one.  It seems like you want to remove problems from some Java files because in your world they are not really problems even though the vanilla Java Compiler thinks they are.

Instead, you should register a `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResourceChangeListener` with the workspace.  Set it to be notified with the  `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD` flag.  Like this:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener(myListener, POST_BUILD);
```

You should do this when your plugin is being started.  This will give you notification after all builds of any project in the workspace.  When a project that you are interested pops up, you can delete all of the Java problem markers:

```
interestingProject.deleteMarkers(
    IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER, 
    true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

This will remove all Java markers that the Java compiler adds.  You can then go around and add back the ones that you need.

A warning, though: the operation above is not fast and will probably take several seconds to scan through all the files of even medium sized projects.  You can be much more intelligent about exactly what files you delete, but that takes more code and a deeper knowledge of the API.  The snippets above should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Andrew, That's not exactly what I want. Let me give sample here.